# How can I create an efficient infinitely looping waving text animation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

This is the effect I am trying to create ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/w3w695ck/5/)):

```
$('.header h1 span').each(function() { // each letter is contained inside a <span> element
    var that = $(this);
    setTimeout(function() {
        that.animate({
                top: "-10px"
            }, animateTime / 2)
            .animate({
                top: "10px"
            }, animateTime / 2);
    }, that.index() * 100);
});
```

Result:

[image: dzzpop]

It appears to be successful. However, I ran into the problem of it looking like this after switching tabs, then coming back:

[image: dzzpop]

In the fiddle above, I've tried to "fix" this by making the animation stop when the tab is unfocused. It's better than when I WASN'T checking for tab unfocusing, but it still has problems. This is the code I'm using to do that:

```
var running = true;

document.addEventListener('visibilitychange', function(){
    console.log("Running:" + running);
    running = !document.hidden;
    if(!running) clearQueues();
})
```

If the user spends less than a couple seconds unfocused from the tab, the animation looks like the second GIF again, and I don't see a way to avoid that. I've tried using `requestAnimationFrame()` but I can't figure out how to make it behave correctly.

So, my question is: **how do I prevent the animation from being affected by the tab being unfocused?**

Bonus points (figuratively) if you can help me make it more efficient on mobile, too.

Comment: what do you mean with "bonus points"?

Comment: What about simply using the gif that has the effect you seek already?

Comment: @CeylanMumunKocabaş Simply a joke; there aren't any "points," but I'd appreciate somebody providing answers to that sub-question, although it is not in any way required.

Comment: @JonSG The GIF was made with code, but I'm assuming you know that and am wondering why I don't animate it myself in GIF format. The largest reason being that I'd simply like to learn how to achieve this effect with code, but I'd also like to stray away from lots of images on the page.

Comment: @Xatenev Thank you! I was in the "danger zone" before posting this so that's wonderful to hear :]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this solves the stuttering for you or not.  This strategy is similar in concept to what you are doing, but uses CSS animation rather than js.

```js
(function(){
  
  var el = document.querySelectorAll(".wavey")[0];
  var oldText = el.innerText
  var newHtml = "";
  for (var i in el.innerText) { newHtml += ("<span style='animation-delay: " + i/10 + "s;'>" + oldText[i] + "</span>"); }
  el.innerHTML = newHtml;
  
})();
```

```css
@keyframes wave {
  from { transform: translateY(0); }
  to { transform: translateY(-1em); }
}

h1.wavey { margin-top: 2em; }

h1.wavey span {
  display: inline-block;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  animation-name: wave;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="wavey">Hello World</h1>
```

Comment: This is perfect, thank you so much! I'll most likely use this; however, is there any way to make it more "floaty" rather than "bouncy?"

Comment: you can add to the h1.wavey span css an easing such as animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;  I'll update my answer with it

Comment: Wonderful! Haha, you also earned those bonus points. Great job!